# Mapping from sparse key space to dense key space

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of events which has a UUID identifying the browsers. Given this sparse key space, I'd like to map to a dense key space.

Besides Bloom Filters, what other options do I have?

If I could have something which mapped to a 64 bit value, it would be perfect, especially if it were algorithmic rather than a lookup table.

Comment: I don't see how using Bloom Filters would do the mapping. Bloom Filters are meant to answer the `is a member` question by `no` or `maybe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of events is constant and not dynamic, you could use a Minimal Perfect Hashing function.

Comment: The UUID is a real UUID, thus 2**128 possibilities. That's a lot of items.

Comment: But is the set of UUIDs known beforehand?  Even if not, if the set doesn't change frequently, libraries like CMPH can be used to generate perfect hashing functions in reasonably small amounts of time, which can then be evaluated extremely quickly.

Comment: New UUIDs are generated constantly. We don't know which ones we'll encounter later. We can tolerate a certain amount of collisions, but we'd obviously like this to be as low as possible.

Comment: What exactly are your goals here? How do you define success in terms of your application? Do you simply want to find a previously encountered UUID in the list of UUIDS quickly with the fewest CPU cycles and a parsimonious use of memory? How many UUIDS in the list, approximately?

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee zero collisions, use any standard dictionary/symbol table algorithm.  That's what they do.

For minimal collisions, there are all sorts of hash functions available.  Bob Jenkins' lookup3.c is fairly popular.  A question you then have to ask yourself is if you will be subject to maliciously chosen UUIDs.  If so, you need a better hash function and a secure random salt.  (If you can tolerate the speed, a keyed HMAC is the perfect way to go for this.)